# Oracle datapump export/import

Tags: oracle, datapump

I tried to do a full Datapump exp on our Dbase.
But resorted to just backing up the table spaces we were working on.

Then I imported using table_exists_action=replace;

Afterwards unfortunately all the Grants on objects are lost... grants 
For procedures and functions and I imagine others as well...

Why would the grants to the procedures be lost after importing using table_exists_action=replace; ?
Is there some other way of running the import to get the grants on the prcedures.. in fact everything on the tablespaces
I'm importing ?

I suppose I can fix that by doing the Grant on the Objects ( procedures, functions, etc ) one by one provided the procedures
apply to the schema they're in. When I do so however a few of them wouldn't get granted/wouldn't work.

Looks like we would really need to be able to accomplish a full dbase exp and imp...

What would we need to have in place for this to work ?

If I tried a full Datapump export I get a fatal error I imagine it's due to the excessive size of the dump file ( 30.25 GB ) to our
Linux server backup folder ?? see below

1.Total estimation using BLOCKS method: 30.25 GB

Then..

Total estimation using BLOCKS method: 30.25 GB
Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/PRE_SYSTEM_IMPCALLOUT/MARKER
Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/PRE_INSTANCE_IMPCALLOUT/MARKER
Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/TABLESPACE
Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/PROFILE
Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/SYS_USER/USER
Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/SCHEMA/USER
Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/ROLE
Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/RADM_FPTM
Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/GRANT/SYSTEM_GRANT/PROC_SYSTEM_GRANT
Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/SCHEMA/GRANT/SYSTEM_GRANT
Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/SCHEMA/ROLE_GRANT
Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/SCHEMA/DEFAULT_ROLE
Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/SCHEMA/ON_USER_GRANT
Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/SCHEMA/TABLESPACE_QUOTA
Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/RESOURCE_COST
Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/SCHEMA/DB_LINK
Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/TRUSTED_DB_LINK
Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/SCHEMA/SEQUENCE/SEQUENCE
Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/SCHEMA/SEQUENCE/GRANT/OWNER_GRANT/OBJECT_GRANT
Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/DIRECTORY/DIRECTORY
Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/DIRECTORY/GRANT/OWNER_GRANT/OBJECT_GRANT
Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/DIRECTORY/GRANT/WITH_GRANT_OPTION/OBJECT_GRANT
Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/DIRECTORY/GRANT/CROSS_SCHEMA/OBJECT_GRANT
Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/CONTEXT
Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/SCHEMA/PUBLIC_SYNONYM/SYNONYM
Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/SCHEMA/SYNONYM
Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/SCHEMA/TYPE/TYPE_SPEC
Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/SCHEMA/TYPE/GRANT/OWNER_GRANT/OBJECT_GRANT
Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/SYSTEM_PROCOBJACT/PRE_SYSTEM_ACTIONS/PROCACT_SYSTEM
Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/SYSTEM_PROCOBJACT/PROCOBJ
Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/SYSTEM_PROCOBJACT/POST_SYSTEM_ACTIONS/PROCACT_SYSTEM
Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/SCHEMA/PROCACT_SCHEMA
Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/EARLY_OPTIONS/VIEWS_AS_TABLES/TABLE
Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/EARLY_POST_INSTANCE_IMPCALLOUT/MARKER
Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/NORMAL_OPTIONS/TABLE
Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/NORMAL_OPTIONS/VIEWS_AS_TABLES/TABLE
Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/NORMAL_POST_INSTANCE_IMPCALLOU/MARKER
Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/SCHEMA/TABLE/TABLE
Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/SCHEMA/TABLE/GRANT/OWNER_GRANT/OBJECT_GRANT
Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/SCHEMA/TABLE/COMMENT
Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/SCHEMA/PACKAGE/PACKAGE_SPEC
Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/SCHEMA/PACKAGE/GRANT/OWNER_GRANT/OBJECT_GRANT
Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/SCHEMA/FUNCTION/FUNCTION
Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/SCHEMA/FUNCTION/GRANT/OWNER_GRANT/OBJECT_GRANT
Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/SCHEMA/PROCEDURE/PROCEDURE
Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/SCHEMA/PROCEDURE/GRANT/OWNER_GRANT/OBJECT_GRANT
Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/SCHEMA/PACKAGE/COMPILE_PACKAGE/PACKAGE_SPEC/ALTER_PACKAGE_SPEC
Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/SCHEMA/FUNCTION/ALTER_FUNCTION
Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/SCHEMA/PROCEDURE/ALTER_PROCEDURE
Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/SCHEMA/TABLE/INDEX/INDEX
Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/SCHEMA/TABLE/CONSTRAINT/CONSTRAINT
Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/SCHEMA/TABLE/INDEX/STATISTICS/INDEX_STATISTICS
Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/SCHEMA/VIEW/VIEW
Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/SCHEMA/VIEW/GRANT/OWNER_GRANT/OBJECT_GRANT
Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/SCHEMA/VIEW/COMMENT
Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/SCHEMA/PACKAGE_BODIES/PACKAGE/PACKAGE_BODY
Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/SCHEMA/TYPE/TYPE_BODY
Job "GAPLITE"."EXPORT_JOB_SQLDEV_3526" stopped due to fatal error at Fri Mar 24 12:05:34 2017 elapsed 0 00:16:47

The cmd:

impdp gaplite/gaplite@mbqas DIRECTORY=exp_gaplite DUMPFILE=gaplite_SLAC.dmp LOGFILE=gaplite_SLAC_march282017.log TABLESPACES=GAPLITE,I_IDB,I_PCAP,REIMB,TANDEM_REFRESH,R_PAYMENT,CAPS,PAYMENT,PCAP,TANDEM,HCOM,IREPORTS,R_IDB,I_PAYMENT,DEFER_V2,CLIEN T_MAPPING,IDB,R_CAPS,R_GAPLITE,I_GAPLITE,DB_MOD,PARTNER_CLAIMS,PCAP_WORK,SDP,R_PCAP,UCS,PCAPEOD,I_CAPS,PREPAYMENT,CDC,I_PREPAYMENT,ER EIMBURSEMENT,AUDITCOLLECTIONS,SLDRYRUN,R_DRUGOPS,R_REIMB,R_TANDEM_REFRESH,IMPORT_CAPS,EVENTS,DRUGOPS table_exists_action=replace;

but it looks like I should include the SYSTEM tablespace to maintain grant objects, etc.
or add something like EXCLUDE=CONSTRAINT,REF_CONSTRAINT,INDEX..

Answer (score 0):

Well, from what i rebember, that's a common problem. It may be due to the fact that the grants are being implemented before the user/object creation.
So, basically, store the scripts from those grants to implement them later.